# How to write a recursive permutation method that accepts 2 ints

Tags: java, recursion, int, permutation

I need to write a method that does n!/(n-r)!. This would be easy to do in a for loop but I can't figure it out recursively. Here is my code so far.

```
public static int permut(int n, int r) {
    if (r == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (r==1){
        return n;
    } else {    
        return n * permut(n, r-1)/permut(n,r-1);
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to setup the return.

Comment: You'll need to figure out how to call `permut` with at least one of the parameters being smaller (`n-1` or `r-1`).  That's going to take a bit of mathematical thinking.  If you had permut(n,r-1) or permut(n-1,r) [just as an example], how could you get the result from that?

Comment: I think I would reduce r because that's essentially the amount of iterations it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you can think of this the same as a normal factorial, accept that you decrement `n` and `r` each recursion and stop when `r == 1` instead of `n == 1`.

```
public static int permut(int n, int r){
    if(r == 1) return n;
    return n*permut(n-1, r-1);
}
```

So if `n = 10` and `r = 3`, you need `10!/(10-3)!` or `10*9*8`, and the program will give:

```
n = 10, r = 3, val = 10
n = 9,  r = 2, val = 10*9
n = 8,  r = 1, val = 10*9*8
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I wasn't understanding how to make it run r amount of times but reducing r until it hits 1 makes sense now.